# CiviMail pull-downs not displaying correctly

Tags: civimail

After upgrading to 4.6.2, the pull-down menus are not displaying correctly in the Define Mailing window. Each pull-down is displaying as two separate elements.

I have attached a screen shot and the section of HTML which corresponds to the template selection window.

By the way, I implemented the PRs relating to issue [CRM-16277](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16277).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Screenshot:

[image: CiviMail error screenshot]

HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="MsgTemplateCtrl" class="ng-scope">
   <div class="select2-container ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope" id="s2id_crmUiId_5">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice select2-default" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-6">Message Template</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen6" class="select2-offscreen">{{crmUiField.title}}*</label><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-6" id="s2id_autogen6">
      <div class="select2-drop select2-display-none crm-container select2-with-searchbox">
         <div class="select2-search">       <label for="s2id_autogen6_search" class="select2-offscreen">{{crmUiField.title}}*</label>       <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-6" id="s2id_autogen6_search">   </div>
         <ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-6">   </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
   <select crm-ui-id="subform.msg_template_id" name="msg_template_id" crm-ui-select="{dropdownAutoWidth : true, allowClear: true, placeholder: ts('Message Template')}" ng-model="mailing.msg_template_id" ng-change="loadTemplate(mailing, mailing.msg_template_id)" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope" id="crmUiId_5" tabindex="-1" title="{{crmUiField.title}}*">
      <option value=""></option>
      <!-- ngRepeat: frm in crmMsgTemplates.getAll() | orderBy:'msg_title' -->
      <option ng-repeat="frm in crmMsgTemplates.getAll() | orderBy:'msg_title'" ng-value="frm.id" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="133">

[removed list of options]

  <!-- end ngRepeat: frm in crmMsgTemplates.getAll() | orderBy:'msg_title' -->
   </select>
   <a crm-icon="disk" ng-click="saveTemplate(mailing)" class="crm-hover-button ng-isolate-scope" title="Save As"><span class="icon ui-icon-disk"></span> </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start by going through the steps for [troubleshooting javascript in CiviCRM](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Coleman. I guess that I did something wrong when making the Pull Request changes for issue [CRM-16277](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16277), but I can't find the problem. I wasn't even sure which of the six PR changes to make, so it's maybe not surprising that it didn't work. Looks like we will have to abandon CiviMail until 4.6.3.